# How to send a snmpget request to a remote router?

Tags: router, snmp, network-discovery

I need to get the IP routing table from a remote router which is not situated on my network, got this from `http://www.sharontools.com/online-lab/device/?q=cisco-r2` i have enabled snmp and created snmp users on the router, now i need to send a snmpget request to this router with the OID for the IP routing table, but when i send a request to an address(IP) from the list of interfaces which are up on this router, I am getting Timed Out error? where am i going wrong and what is the correct way to do this ?

Edit 1 : Now i am able to fire snmp requests to the router, but when i do a snmpwalk on the ipRouteTable object i get the following error

```
IP-MIB::ip.21 = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
```

the user belongs to a group with a view which has write access to iso.

Edit 2 : Adding the snmp related configs from the output of `show running-config` command, the user belongs to Group: `GROUP2`:

```
snmp-server group GROUP1 v3 priv read ALL-ACCESS 
snmp-server group GROUP2 v3 priv write ROUTE-TABLE 
snmp-server group NetOps v3 priv 
snmp-server view ALL-ACCESS iso included
snmp-server view ALL-ACCESS internet included
snmp-server view ALL-ACCESS ip.21 included
snmp-server view ROUTE-TABLE ip.21 included
snmp-server community public RO
snmp-server community private RW
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkdown linkup coldstart warmstart
snmp-server enable traps flowmon
snmp-server enable traps transceiver all
snmp-server enable traps call-home message-send-fail server-fail
snmp-server enable traps tty
snmp-server enable traps rf
snmp-server enable traps memory
snmp-server enable traps cpu_threshold
snmp-server enable traps eigrp
snmp-server enable traps ospf state-change
snmp-server enable traps ospf errors
snmp-server enable traps ospf retransmit
snmp-server enable traps ospf lsa
snmp-server enable traps ospf cisco-specific state-change nssa-trans-change
snmp-server enable traps ospf cisco-specific state-change shamlink interface
snmp-server enable traps ospf cisco-specific state-change shamlink neighbor
snmp-server enable traps ospf cisco-specific errors
snmp-server enable traps ospf cisco-specific retransmit    
snmp-server enable traps ospf cisco-specific lsa
snmp-server enable traps flex-links status
snmp-server enable traps fru-ctrl
snmp-server enable traps entity
snmp-server enable traps ethernet cfm cc mep-up mep-down cross-connect loop config
snmp-server enable traps ethernet cfm crosscheck mep-missing mep-unknown service-up
snmp-server enable traps ether-oam
snmp-server enable traps aaa_server
snmp-server enable traps flash insertion removal
snmp-server enable traps l2tc threshold sys-threshold
snmp-server enable traps power-ethernet police
snmp-server enable traps rep
snmp-server enable traps vswitch dual-active vsl
snmp-server enable traps udld link-fail-rpt status-change
snmp-server enable traps vtp
snmp-server enable traps vlancreate
snmp-server enable traps vlandelete
snmp-server enable traps auth-framework sec-violation
snmp-server enable traps dot1x auth-fail-vlan guest-vlan no-auth-fail-vlan no-guest-vlan
snmp-server enable traps envmon fan shutdown supply temperature status
snmp-server enable traps entity-diag boot-up-fail hm-test-recover hm-thresh-reached scheduled-test-fail
snmp-server enable traps port-security
snmp-server enable traps ethernet evc status create delete
snmp-server enable traps energywise        
snmp-server enable traps ipsla
snmp-server enable traps vstack
snmp-server enable traps bfd
snmp-server enable traps bgp
snmp-server enable traps bulkstat collection transfer
snmp-server enable traps cef resource-failure peer-state-change peer-fib-state-change inconsistency
snmp-server enable traps config-copy
snmp-server enable traps config
snmp-server enable traps config-ctid
snmp-server enable traps event-manager
snmp-server enable traps hsrp
snmp-server enable traps ipmulticast
snmp-server enable traps isis
snmp-server enable traps msdp
snmp-server enable traps pim neighbor-change rp-mapping-change invalid-pim-message
snmp-server enable traps bridge newroot topologychange
snmp-server enable traps stpx inconsistency root-inconsistency loop-inconsistency    
snmp-server enable traps syslog
snmp-server enable traps isakmp policy add
snmp-server enable traps isakmp policy delete
snmp-server enable traps isakmp tunnel start
snmp-server enable traps isakmp tunnel stop
snmp-server enable traps ipsec cryptomap add
snmp-server enable traps ipsec cryptomap delete
snmp-server enable traps ipsec cryptomap attach
snmp-server enable traps ipsec cryptomap detach
snmp-server enable traps ipsec tunnel start
snmp-server enable traps ipsec tunnel stop
snmp-server enable traps ipsec too-many-sas
snmp-server enable traps errdisable
snmp-server enable traps ethernet cfm alarm
snmp-server enable traps vlan-membership
snmp-server enable traps mac-notification change move threshold
snmp-server enable traps vrfmib vrf-up vrf-down vnet-trunk-up vnet-trunk-down
```

Comment: can you post your router snmp configuration

Comment: u want me to post the output of show running-config command ?